# Post form to external URL

Tags: forms, 8, uri, redirection

I need to POST the data in a form to an external URL.

In Drupal 7, you would use

```
$form['#action'] = url('http://example.com', array('external' => true));
```

Or maybe this was for GET. Anyway... in Drupal 8, this does not work. I have tried editing the submitForm method:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('http://example.com');
    $response->send();
}
```

This works, however I have not found a way to submit the values of the form along with the request. I looked at the httpClient class, but it seems that is for sending/requesting data only and does not redirect the user.

Hope someone can help me out. If it comes down to it I am fine with using GET instead.

Comment: As side note, in Drupal 7 `url('http://example.com', array('external' => true));` is perfectly useless; just use `'http://example.com'`. `url()` just returns a string, not an object.

Answer (score 3):

`$form['#action']` works the same, Drupal 7 or Drupal 8. It needs a string, which is what `url()` returns in Drupal 7. The reason why `url()` is normally used is because the code has a relative path for a routing item, such as in `url('comment/reply/'. $edit['nid'])`.

In Drupal 8, for example, the Comment module uses the following code.

```
$form['#action'] = $this->url('comment.reply', array('entity_type' => $entity->getEntityTypeId(), 'entity' => $entity->id(), 'field_name' => $field_name));
```

[`UrlGeneratorTrait::url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorTrait.php/function/UrlGeneratorTrait%3A%3Aurl/8.2.x), the method called in that code, still returns a string, not an object. Also in this case, `UrlGeneratorTrait::url()` is used because the code has a route name (comment.reply) and it wants to get the URL for that route.

The following code works for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

```
$form['#action'] = 'http://example.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out. It turns out that the Drupal 7 method works, however there is no longer a need to submit a URL object, just a string containing the URL. So

`$form['#action'] = url('http://example.com', array('external' => true));`

becomes simply

`$form['#action'] = 'http://example.com';`

Comment: but if you do this, you skip the validation

Comment: FYI, the Webform module now supports POST to external URLs.

Answer (score 0):

your sample code would work just fine for simple redirection.

However for posting data to external URL, this should work i believe,

```php
$response = \Drupal::httpClient()->post($host, [
        'form_params' => $fields,
        'headers' => [
          'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
    ]);
```

Answered Similar Question in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288929/18756